# Create a new variable based on value across columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is similar to a simplified version below:

```
MO1<-c("0","1","2","3")
MO2<-c("1","0","3","2")
MO3<-c("3","2","1","0")
df<-data.frame(MO1,MO2,MO3)
df
```

I am trying to create a new variable that would scan through the observations looking for all the 1 values. I would then like the observations in this new variable to take on the name of the column variable that it was obtained from, see below:

```
MO1<-c("0","1","2","3")
MO2<-c("1","0","3","2")
MO3<-c("3","2","1","0")
MOTIVATION<-c("MO2","MO1","MO3","")
df2<-data.frame(MO1,MO2,MO3,MOTIVATION)
df2
```

Sorry, I do not know how to just show the resulting data frame, df2 from above.

I have 989 observations and 19 different MO.. variables in my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
> ind <- which(df==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
> df2 <- df   # just cloning df
> df2$MOTIVATION <- NA
> df2$MOTIVATION[ind[,1]] <- names(df) [ind[,2]]
> df2
  MO1 MO2 MO3 MOTIVATION
1   0   1   3        MO2
2   1   0   2        MO1
3   2   3   1        MO3
4   3   2   0       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Try `max.col` like this.  Insert a 1 in front of each row and then find the column of the last 1.  Subtract 1 so that it corresponds tot he original column numbers and a missing 1 gives 0.  Then replace all zeros with NA and look up the corresponding column names.

```
ix <- max.col(cbind(1, df) == 1, "last") - 1
transform(df, MOTIVATION = names(df)[replace(ix, ix == 0, NA)])
```

giving:

```
  MO1 MO2 MO3 MOTIVATION
1   0   1   3        MO2
2   1   0   2        MO1
3   2   3   1        MO3
4   3   2   0       <NA>
```

**2)** A variation would be the following.  We compute `max.col` and then multiply each result by 1 if there is a 1 in that row or NA if not.

```
df1 <- df == 1
transform(df, MOTIVATION = names(df)[max.col(df1) * match(rowSums(df1), 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `apply` in combination with `which` as:

```
df$MOTIVATION <- apply(df,1,function(x)names(df)[which(x==1)])
df
#    MO1 MO2 MO3 MOTIVATION
# 1   0   1   3        MO2
# 2   1   0   2        MO1
# 3   2   3   1        MO3
# 4   3   2   0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, is there a way to limit which columns/variables in the data frame that I can look for 1s? I have other columns/variables that also have 1s in them. When I run your script the new variable has the names of all the columns/variables that have 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick (note that this support the case where two Columns have "1" not sure if this was a valid edge case for you. 
(I slightly modified MO4 from original so that it would contain two "1"

```
MO1<-c("0","1","2","3")
MO2<-c("1","2","3","2")
MO3<-c("3","2","1","0")
MO4<-c("3","2","1","1")
df<-data.frame(MO1,MO2,MO3,MO4)
df


findx <- function(dfx) 
{
  idx <- which(dfx=="1")
  res <- lapply(idx, function(x) paste0('MO', x))
  res
}

found <- apply(df,2,findx)

newdf <- unlist(found)
newdf
```

With an ouput of

"MO2" "MO1" "MO3" "MO3" "MO4"